# Option to remove column headers in data export in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am exporting data from SAPUI5 app using `Export` and `ExportTypeCSV` controls from `sap.ui.core.util` library in txt and xls formats using `fileExtension` property.

The columns are being set as below:

```
columnTemp = [{
                    name: "Column 1",
                    template: {
                        content: "{Column1Path}"
                    }
                }, {
                    name: "Column 2",
                    template: {
                        content: "{Column2Path}"
                    }]
```

The columns headings are not required to be a part of the downloaded files since the files are to be processed further containing just the data. If I don't set the '`name`' itself, and create each entry using just '`template`', then the result is achieved but a blank line exists at the top of the file.

Is there another way to remove column headers for all fields in the file? Or should I consider `sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet` control? (I was unable to find file-extension-like property for it)

Kindly assist.